# Error referencing Class inside another Class

Tags: java, list

In my CD class and TrackList class I have an object called tracklist that comes up as an error. I don't know what I need to add or remove to fix it.
Here is my CD class:

```
public class CD {
    public String artist;
    public String title;
    public trackist myTracklist;

    public CD(String artist, String title){
        artist = artist;
        title = title;
        myTracklist = new tracklist(100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mainArtist;
        String mainTitle;
        CD myCD = new CD("RisingNation", "Natioins");
        mainArtist = myCD.getArtist();
        System.out.println(mainArtist);
        mainTitle = myCD.getTitle();
        System.out.println(mainTitle);
        myCD.display();
    }

    public String getArtist(){
        String person;
        person = artist;
        return person;
    }
}
```

Also here is my tracklist class,

```
public class TrackList {
    int length;
    int numUsed;
    String[] storage;

    public tracklist(int size){// this shows up underlined in red
        length = size;
        numUsed = 0;
        storage = new String[length];
    }

    public int count(){
        return numUsed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the compiler doesn't know whether `tracklist` should be a method, since there was no return type, Or a constructor since it doesn't match the class name. But it seems to me that it should be a constructor.

So change the code to :

```
public TrackList(int size)
```

You should also change the CD class constructor like :

```
public CD(String artist, String title){
    this.artist = artist;
    this.title = title;
    myTracklist = new tracklist(100);
}
```

Since the constructor parameters have the same names as the class global variables, you need to refer to the global variables with `this.`.

Answer (score 0):

That line should be Constructor right?

Constructor name should be the same as Class name. Case is sensitive. This mean, if your class are

```
    public class TrackList {}
```

So the constructor must be

```
    public TrackList () {}
```